# PHP comparing two strings return false

Tags: php, mysqli

I am reading records from database and stored in tab separated .txt file. In my database Id is o7 (field ID is varchar). when I write it to file it displays as 7. It creates problem while comparing the string It gives 07 and 7 false. How I can ensure that same field i.e.07 will written on file?
My php code is

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
        $output.=strval($row[id])."\t".$row[title]."\n";          

     }
     fwrite( $fp1,$output);
     fclose($fp1);
```

Comment: In my database id is string. i.e. Numeric as well as alpha. e.g. DMERT  is another id in mydatabase.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format id field:

```
$output.=sprintf("%.2d\t%s\n", $row[id], $row[title]);
```

Then `id` will go in the file as '07'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    if($row[id]<10)
          $output.='0'.strval($row[id])."\t".$row[title]."\n";

    else          

          $output.=strval($row[id])."\t".$row[title]."\n";

 }
 fwrite( $fp1,$output);
 fclose($fp1);
```